# Retrieving params in a WEB API POST method

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, http, asp.net-web-api

In my web api I am primarily using POST methods so the client can send function parameters using JSON. However, I noticed that having a model (dto) for these params on both the client and server doesn't really make sense. Or does it?

Since I am using POST is creating a model object for binding required? Sometimes I am actually dealing with an entity like Customer and it makes complete sense, but when I am dealing with 3 random parameters do I really have to create a model (dto) so I can retrieve the data into the POST function?

Here is my POST function in my WEB API:

```
[HttpPost, Route("GetAccountInformation")]
public IActionResult RetrieveAccountInformation(GetAccountInformationParamsObj myParams)
{
    var retVal = _repository.GetAccountInformation(myParams.StartDate, myParams.EndDate, myParams.Count)

    return Ok(retVal);
}
```

Here is an example of what the client will send in the POST body:

```
{
    "StartDate":"10-25-2015",
    "EndDate":"11-25-2015",
    "Count":20
}
```

It would be great if the following would work but the param values end up being empty when making the request:

```
[HttpPost, Route("GetAccountInformation")]
    public IActionResult RetrieveAccountInformation([FromBody] DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate, int count = 0)
    {

    }
```

Comment: I'm having trouble following what it is you're actually asking.  The use of an actual model isn't *required* for any HTTP interaction, it's simply a way of semantically grouping and understanding objects in your domain.  Does that `params` thing even compile?  I would have thought that was a reserved keyword.  Also, you're talking about POST requests, but your method is `Get`.  Can you clarify what you're asking?

Comment: I apologize for the params name and the confusion with the function name. i updated everything to make more sense. I wanted to know if the use of an actual model is required for an HTTP POST interaction. If not then how can the client send me JSON parameters and I retrieve them without using an actual model? For example: The client is a vb6 application and the developer of the VB6 application wants to call GetAccountInformation in my Web API. The developer will send JSON that contains the 3 params and I will return a list of results in JSON.

Comment: You *might* be able to just have individual value types as parameters on your server-side method instead of a model.  (At least, MVC allows that.  The semantics of WebAPI might make it a little weird though.)  But it seems more sensible to just organize the values into a class anyway.

Comment: Hmm I wonder if it is case sensitive because my first attempt didn't work. If MVC allows it then Web API should allow it and that would answer my question completely.

Comment: `"If MVC allows it then Web API should allow it"` - That's not necessarily true.  The main difference between the two frameworks is semantics, and those semantics can lead to very different ways of implementing things.

Comment: After doing some research I believe I found that with Web API you can't retrieve multiple params from the body.

Comment: No it is not posssible. But you can send data as namevaluecollection.

Answer (score 2):

You dont need to do a `POST`, what you trying to do doesn't justify a `POST`, just try to get the data from uri using the *Attr* `[FromUri]` like this:

```
[HttpGet, Route("GetAccountInformation")]
public IActionResult Get([FromUri]GetAccountInformationParamsObj @params)
{
    var retVal = _repository.GetAccountInformation(@params.StartDate, @params.EndDate, @params.Count)

    return Ok(retVal);
}
```

and make the request like this:

> **/GetAccountInformation?StartDate=10-25-2015&EndDate=11-25-2015&Count=20**

Comment: I would have to agree that this is an ideal scenario to use GET but as a design decision we decided to create the Web API so it receives all POSTS. Primarily because there is a limit to how many query string params you can have and because we will be sending sensitive data as params.

Comment: Sure, but for this it solve, no?, use POST for this isn't semantic. _Any HTTP request message is allowed to contain
a message body, and thus must parse messages with that in mind.
Server semantics for GET, however, are restricted such that a body,
if any, has no semantic meaning to the request. The requirements
on parsing are separate from the requirements on method semantics.

So, yes, you can send a body with GET, and no, it is never useful
to do so._

Comment: Do you know if it is at least possible to bind params directly from matching JSON in the body when using POST? See my final example above.